# How to disable Pointer stick through registry

Tags: windows-7

How do I permanently disable pointer stick through the registry on a Dell Latitude E6420 and Dell Latitude E6420 in Windows 7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I permanently disable the Dell Pointstick?](http://superuser.com/questions/441724/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to do this the hard way to find out more how Windows works. Well, system-wide software settings are located under HKLM\Software. I had a quick check on my Dell Latitude E6230 (Win8) and for me the specific key would be HKLM\Software\Alps\Apoint. Under that key I had several subkeys each with multiple values relating to different aspects of my pointer software. You should have something very similar in your case.

I don't have a pointer on my machine so I can't tell you the exact location of the specific setting to turn off or on the pointer, but in your case I can't imagine it should be too difficult to find. When I looked through my keys all the settings looked self-descriptive. I'm assuming that the value you'll find will be of a Boolean type so if it reads 1 then modify it to 0 and vice versa.

Good luck and hope that helps.